# Как определить элемент на котором сработал click?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

На элементе не срабатывает событие onClick.
Хотя если его перенести в другой компонент то там всё ок.
Как быстрее всего найти элемент который перехватывает это событие?
Есть ли инструменты в отладчике google chrome?

```
<div
    className={`CLASS11`}
    onClick={()=>{
      console.log('нажали');
    }}
  >
    {`кнопка`}
  </div>
```

Comment: можешь просто попробовать выбрать этот элемент, скорее всего его кто-то перекрывает

Comment: Попробуйте вывести это через alert()

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div
    className={`CLASS11`} data-tag={"наши данные"}
    onClick={(event)=>{
      console.log('нажали на: ', event.target);
      console.log('получаем наши данные: ', event.target.getAttribute('data-tag'));
    }}
  >
    {`кнопка`}
  </div>
```